# Avoid Cache Misses for Column Major Access of a 2D Array/Vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, caching, vector

Cache Misses are a big problem for one of the Math Simulation Engines i'm working on. One of them being 2D Array's being accessed in a column major manner. Generally, arrays in memory are store in a contiguos manner in a row major way and when accessed in the column major manner, they will create a lot of cache misses. Say i have an array

```
1 8 3 4 5
3 4 5 6 9
4 3 1 0 2
```

the access to the array is pretty random. For one case, say a random sequence pops up from an output of a specific function = {1, 2, 0, 0, 1}.
This output would translate to the values being
array[1][0], array[2][1], array[0][2], array [0][3] and array[1][4].
If you see this is very random in terms of access across the array. And as arrays are stored as row major way, this would lead to cache misses in terms of how arrays are read in a column major way.

Is there a solution where in I could reduce this issue, because completely removing cache misses is just impossible. The performance hit is noticed when there are lots of these types of operations performed, and this slows the overall performance of the entire program.

Comment: Create the array with its contents flipped, so that all accesses are row major now?